# incluir funciones javascript/jquery en template de backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone, underscorejs

Tengo la siguiente template con una tabla. Se recorre un Array y en la fila de la tabla se crea un enlace

```
<tbody>
<%for(var i=0;i<resultados.length;i++){ %>
 <tr onclick="window.open('#/ensayo/<%- resultados[i].tipoEnsayo %>/<%- resultados[i].idEnsayo %>', '_blank')" class="selectableRow">
   <% if (mostrarResultados.mostrarTipoEnsayo == 1) { %><td><%- resultados[i].tipoEnsayo %></td><%}%>
   <% if (mostrarResultados.mostrarIdEnsayo == 1) { %><td><%- resultados[i].idEnsayo %></td><%}%>
 </tr>
<%}%>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se pincha en el enlace lleva a otra pantalla. El problema viene cuando el idEnsayo contiene "%".

La URL que se forma es la siguiente: `http://localhost:8080/Petrocor/index_1.html#/ensayo/inmersion/EAutoclave_6%Mo-SS_1`

Da error (`Uncaught URIError: URI malformed`) al formar la URL el encode del caracter "%" es "%25"

¿Cómo puedo escapar éste caracter cuando se forma la URL dentro del html, con la sintaxis de underscore?

En javascript sería algo así:

```
var ensayo=resultados[i].idEnsayo;
if(ensayo.includes('%'){
ensayo=ensayo.replace('%','%25');
}
```

Comment: No veo la relación entre la pregunta y el título :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal la pregunta, quieres escapar el identificador del recurso. Lo puedes hacer con `encodeURIComponent`

```js
let baseUrl='http://localhost:8080/Petrocor/index_1.html#/ensayo/inmersion/';
$('button').click(function () {
  let value=$('#texto').val();
  console.log(`el texto es "${value}"`);
  console.log(`El texto listo para una URL es "${baseUrl}${encodeURIComponent(value)}"`);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="texto" value="EAutoclave_6%Mo-SS_1"/>
<button>Pulsa</button>
```

Comment: El problema es que tengo que escapar el '%'  cuando se forma la url: <tr onclick="window.open('#/ensayo/<%- resultados[i].tipoEnsayo %>/<%- resultados[i].idEnsayo %>', '_blank')" class="selectableRow">

Comment: <tr onclick="window.open(encodeURIComponent('#/ensayo/<%- resultados[i].tipoEnsayo %>/<%- resultados[i].idEnsayo %>', '_blank'))" class="selectableRow"> Así afecta a toda la URL y sólo quiero que escape en el componente idEnsayo

Comment: Puedes usarlo sólo para una parte y concatenar, edito para que veas a qué me refiero

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente quedaría así:

```
<tbody>
  <%for(var i=0;i<resultados.length;i++){ %>
    <% var idEnsayo=resultados[i].idEnsayo;%>
    <tr onclick="window.open('#/ensayo/<%- resultados[i].tipoEnsayo %>/${encodeURIComponent(idEnsayo)}', '_blank')" class="selectableRow">
```